# Naming Confusion

Tags: usability, terminology, tabs

I have two applications A and B. A refers to a external application and B refers to the application that is being used. User can sync contacts from A to B or B to A.

I decided to show it in tab format but it seems pretty confusing. What is the possible way to show it without creating confusion. I have attached a screenshot to get a clear picture of what i am talking about
[image: 1]

Comment: Is the data different when syncing between A to B and B to A?

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho : Yes

Answer (score 5):

If B is the main application and A is external application. The process can be called **Push (B to A) and Pull (A to B)**. You can be more descriptive by using the real names such as **Push contact to A**, and **Pull contacts from B**.

Here's a screenshot of Google's mobile version, but it only perform the syncing process without showing any data:

[image]

Comment: Yeah this seems like a better solution. Thanks for the reply :)